# sendRedirect() not working as expected

Tags: java, jsp

I've this `Register.jsp` page which on page load, I want to check if a user is already logged in. So I've this code,

```
<%
    String usertype = (String)session.getAttribute("usertype");
    if(usertype.equals("student")){
        response.sendRedirect("studenthome.jsp");
    }
    else if(usertype.equals("faculty")){
        response.sendRedirect("facultyhome.jsp");
    }       
%>
```

It works when a user is logged in(it redirects to `studenthome.jsp` if `usertype` equals `student` and redirects to `facultyhome.jsp` if `usertype` equals `faculty`), but when `usertype` is `null`, I just want to continue loading the page instead I get following error. What am I doing wrong here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When usertype is null, I just want to continue loading the page
>   instead of getting error.

You will get `NullPointerException` if `usertype` is `null`. You can simply ignore this error by swap the position of `usertype` on `equals` method  of `if-else` condition

```
if("student".equals(usertype)){
    response.sendRedirect("studenthome.jsp");
}
else if("faculty".equals(usertype)){
    response.sendRedirect("facultyhome.jsp");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to avoid *Scriplet* at all in *21st century* instead use [JavaServer Pages Standard Tag Library](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/index-jsp-135995.html)

Try with `c:redirect` and `c:choose`. Find more details about [Oracle Tutorial - Core Tag Library](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/tutorial/doc/JSTL4.html)

---

*There is no need to handle `NullPointerException` using JSTL (in this case) as shown in below sample code.*

Sample code:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>

<c:choose>
    <c:when test="${usertype == 'student'}">
        <c:redirect url="studenthome.jsp" />
    </c:when>
    <c:when test="${usertype == 'faculty'}">
        <c:redirect url="facultyhome.jsp" />
    </c:when>
    <c:otherwise>
        <c:redirect url="home.jsp" />
    </c:otherwise>
</c:choose>
```

*Note:* remove `c:otherwise` if not needed.